# strncpy() core dump when I use Libtar in ubuntu12.04

Tags: c, tar, strncpy

I trace the coredump in the encode.c:33.

The source code like this:

```
if (t->options & TAR_GNU) 
    strncpy(t->th_buf.magic, "ustar  ", 8);    // here is the coredump                                                                                                                                 
else
    ....
```

the function call stack like this:

```
0x4064d73a in strncpy (__len=8, __src=0x40663b34 "ustar  ", __dest=0x4104e5ed "") at /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:121
0x4024e342 in __strncpy_chk () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x4024ee1a in __chk_fail () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x40250065 in __fortify_fail () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x401b739a in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x4017d825 in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x4017a1df in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x40064424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
<signal handler called>
sig_coredump (sig=6) at mpm_common.c:1207
```

the t->th_buf.magic is sturct of tar_header, the defination:

```
struct tar_header{
    ...;
    char magic[6];
    char version[2];
    ...;
}
```

I pretty sure strncpy can use in this way.

And in my case, the t->th_buf has malloc already.

In gdb:

```
(gdb) p t->th_buf
$5 = {name = "/TARFILE.C", '\000' <repeats 89 times>, mode = "100644 ", 
      uid = "    41", gid = "    41 ", size = "     207114 ", mtime = "12115070475 ", 
      chksum = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", typeflag = 48 '0', linkname = '\000' <repeats 99 times>, 
      magic = "\000\000\000\000\000", version = "\000",
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are trying to copy eight bytes into a buffer that only has room for six, that wouldn't normally be a problem.

The reason it's not usually a problem is that there is a two-byte character array immediately following that is perfectly capable of taking the buffer overflow:

```
struct tar_header{
    ...;
    char magic[6];
    char version[2];     // Can absorb extra two chars easily.
    ...;
}
```

---

The real problem with `strncpy` is that most people don't understand how it works.

If the buffer being copied is larger than the size you specify, it basically stops at the size and copies no more, *including the null-terminator at the end of the string.*

Hence `strncpy` can end up giving you something that is *not* a C string and, if you subsequently try to use it as a C string (such as passing it to `strlen`), all hell may break loose.

That's why I prefer to use `strlen` check followed by `strcpy`, assuming the data can't change between the two parts. That way, you're *guaranteed* to end up with a C string (or you know about it before hand).

---

However, that's also not the specific problem here.

Within your call stack, there is a call to a checking function `__strncpy_chk` which goes something like this:

```
char *
__strncpy_chk (s1, s2, n, s1len)
     char *s1;
     const char *s2;
     size_t n;
     size_t s1len;
{
    char c;
    char *s = s1;

    if (__builtin_expect (s1len < n, 0))
        __chk_fail ();
    :
    rest of function to copy the stuff.
}
```

Hence it's checking, *in advance,* whether the source string is too long for the length you've specified, and failing before it even attempts the copy. This is basically doing the same steps I mention earlier but forcing a crash rather than you knowing about it in your own code.

That's where your error is coming from, a bit of extra security in the runtime library.

Keep in mind that this extra check is only in the [debug code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/debug/strncpy_chk.c), not in the [production ready code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strncpy.c). That way, you can confirm that you're doing the right thing during development without it slowing down your code in the field.

Comment: +1 for nice sleuthing - although the string appears to be 7+1 characters long, so exactly eight. Why is it failing the test? Double byte characters because of environment?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found this problem too. But It happened in "libtar" opensource code that i can not modify the code. I write some simple code for using strncpy like this, it's working. But in my projects it coredump, maybe the gcc has some options to check the function strictly. Someone told me to add -fno-stack-protector:) But it seem no helpful.

Comment: @Floris, it's failing the test because `s1len` will either be 5 or 6 (the max string length or the max string size for the **magic** field you're copying too). Both of those values are less than what you're trying to copy in, a seven-char string (size of 8).

Comment: Interesting! I always learn things when I hang around with real software engineers...

Comment: oh yes. I compile release version of my project, the coredump disappear. It's happened in debug version. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to copy 8 bytes:

```
strncpy(t->th_buf.magic, "ustar  ", 8);
```

into a buffer with allocated space for 6

```
char magic[6];
```

Not going to work.

Comment: but use in this way is correct. You can see the struct defination. "char version[2]" follow with "char magic[6]"

Comment: @YifanWang - are you saying you are deliberately) trying to overwrite the `version` at the same time as the `magic`, and that makes it alright? Isn't that dependent on compiler options? Without using some enforced alignment or unions, that seems terribly dangerous to me. What is the address of `version`? Is it indeed 6 bytes past `magic`?

Answer (score 1):

`magic` is only 6 chars and you are writing 8 to it.

Comment: I use gdb print the th_buf, showing the info in the end of my question